# Why json_encode() return keys values twice (index key and string key)?

Tags: php, indexing, key, json

When I use the json_encode() function, the method return a Json with two time the same value: one with the string key and one with an index. I did not have this problem before.

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT mail,description FROM identifiant WHERE mail = :mail AND pass=:pass");
        if ($req->execute(array(
                    'mail' => $_COOKIE['mail'],
                    'pass' => $_COOKIE['pass']))) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');

            return json_encode($req->fetchAll());
```

The response:

```
[
   {
      "mail": "root@root.com",
      "0": "root@root.com",
      "description": "a description",
      "1": "a description"
   }
]
```

How can I do for don't have index keys ?

Comment: He did not realize that the SQL query returned an associative array + normal indexed values.  Down voting the question for that is rather OTT.

Comment: try this one : return  json_encode($req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use PDO::FETCH_ASSOC fetching mode:

```
return json_encode($req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's not `json_encode`, it's because your PDO instance's fetch mode is set to `PDO::FETCH_BOTH`. See the documentation for [`PDOStatement::fetchAll`'s fetch style](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php).

Answer (score 2):

use this:

*PDO::FETCH_ASSOC*: returns an array indexed by column
         name as returned in your result set
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_BOTH* (default): returns an array indexed by
         both column name and 0-indexed column number as returned in your
         result set
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_BOUND*: returns **`TRUE`** and assigns the
         values of the columns in your result set to the PHP variables to which
         they were bound with the  PDOStatement::bindColumn()
         method
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_CLASS*: returns a new instance of the
         requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to named
         properties in the class. If *fetch_style*
         includes PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE (e.g. *PDO::FETCH_CLASS |
         PDO::FETCH_CLASSTYPE*) then the name of the class is
         determined from a value of the first column.
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_INTO*: updates an existing instance
         of the requested class, mapping the columns of the result set to
         named properties in the class
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_LAZY*: combines
         *PDO::FETCH_BOTH* and *PDO::FETCH_OBJ*,
         creating the object variable names as they are accessed
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_NUM*: returns an array indexed by column
         number as returned in your result set, starting at column 0
        
        
         *PDO::FETCH_OBJ*: returns an anonymous object with
         property names that correspond to the column names returned in your
         result set

[PDOStatement::fetch](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
return json_encode($req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use PDO::FETCH__ASSOC as a parameter

```
$req = $bdd->prepare("SELECT mail,description FROM identifiant WHERE mail = :mail AND pass=:pass");
        if ($req->execute(array(
                    'mail' => $_COOKIE['mail'],
                    'pass' => $_COOKIE['pass']))) {
            header('Content-type: application/json');

  return  json_encode($req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

}